# Edit property in entity framework in contructor

Tags: c#, entity-framework, encryption

I need to decrypt a Password after my object comes out of the database, how can I achieve this? This is my encrpytion and decryption code:

```
public class EncryptionHelper {
    public static string Encrypt(string strToEncrypt) {
        try {
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider objDESCrypto = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider objHashMD5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] byteHash, byteBuff;
            string strTempKey = Settings.Default.Keyword;
            byteHash = objHashMD5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strTempKey));
            objHashMD5 = null;
            objDESCrypto.Key = byteHash;
            objDESCrypto.Mode = CipherMode.ECB; //CBC, CFB
            byteBuff = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strToEncrypt);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(objDESCrypto.CreateEncryptor().
                TransformFinalBlock(byteBuff, 0, byteBuff.Length));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return strToEncrypt;
        }
    }

    public static string Decrypt(string strEncrypted) {
        try {
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider objDESCrypto =
                new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider objHashMD5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] byteHash, byteBuff;
            string strTempKey = Settings.Default.Keyword;
            byteHash = objHashMD5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strTempKey));
            objHashMD5 = null;
            objDESCrypto.Key = byteHash;
            objDESCrypto.Mode = CipherMode.ECB; //CBC, CFB
            byteBuff = Convert.FromBase64String(strEncrypted);
            string strDecrypted = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString
            (objDESCrypto.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock
            (byteBuff, 0, byteBuff.Length));
            objDESCrypto = null;
            return strDecrypted;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return "Wrong Input. " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my entity:

```
public partial class S0Pin
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Serialnumber { get; set; }
    public string Pin { get; set; }

    public virtual User Creator { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the method to insert the object

```
public bool AddS0Pin(S0Pin pin) {
    log.Debug("add s0pin with serialnumber " + pin.Serialnumber);
    var s0pin = S0Pin.SingleOrDefault(pn => pn.Serialnumber == pin.Serialnumber);
    if (s0pin != null) {
        s0pin.Pin = EncryptionHelper.Encrypt(pin.Pin);
    } else {
        this.S0Pin.Add(pin);
    }
    return this.SaveChanges() > 0;
}
```

How can I decrypt the data **after** I got the out of the database? Best way would be in the entity.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to decrypt the passwords? Making it possible to view the password is a huge security flaw, and the best way to go is with an MD5 Hash, which is 1 hash to many inputs AND it cannot be (conclusively) reversed. The way it should be is that you encrypt the password again for your comparison

Sorry, I can't give you an answer, just an observation

Comment: I can't use the decrypted password cause I need to store the passwords of security tokens and certificates ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it isn't a great idea to decrypt the password at all. However, sometimes you need to do that especially if you are building something like a Password Manager with a Show Password functionality.

Second, from what I understand, you want to be able to access the decrypted password via a property in your entity. I would just create another property called DecryptedPassword and call DecryptPassword within that in the getter.

Something like this:

```
public String DecryptPassword
{
    get
    {
        return Decrypt(this.Pin);
    }
}
```

Going a step further, I would create a partial class of the Entity and dump this property in there to ensure that I don't mess with any generated code.

Hope this meets the requirement.

Comment: After very much googleling, I found the same solution and made it like that :) The reason why I need to decrypt, is because I need them for `X509Certificates` and security token ;)